# Treat div as a nonexistent element in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is adding a `display:inline` all that is needed for the browser display to treat the `<div>` as a nonexistent element (do want to consider everything inside the `div` though) in HTML?

I was thinking of having this `div` simply as a placeholder to put content into it from javascript and I was wondering whether it would be a good idea to make it `display:inline`

**NOTE** By nonexistent I mean that if the user says he wants to display the following on the page

```
<something here>
    <something else here />
    ....
</something here>
```

Then the end result on the UI would be exactly what he wanted.  Putting a `div` around it currently is adding a newline between this and other things.

I add this `div`s around something the user (the user being the programmer that is using the functionality I write) outputs in a function.  I want to keep this `div`s completely invisible to the user.  Currently there is a new line injected at times.  For example there is a newline in between the two buttons

```
<div>
    <button>Something</button>
    <div>
        <button>Else</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does 'non-existent' mean?

Comment: What do you mean by 'non-existent element'? display:inline converts a block element (p, h1) to an inline element (b,i,u)

Comment: I'm guessing you mean an element that doesn't produce a line-break after it so if it's empty it doesn't disrupt the other elements.  In which case, yes.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Sorry!  I updated my question above

Comment: @jeff Tagging you too!

Comment: @Deryck thanks! what about when its not empty and it has something in it?

Comment: It will conform to the shape of what's inside unless you specify width and height or if it's a special element that uses styling like `position: absolute` or `fixed`, etc.  PS - you shouldn't do this.  if you are going to load something there, instead leave the `div` there and put a loader animation or an empty block so the browser doesn't shift everything around when it's populated.  set a height/width too

Comment: I still can only guess what a 'nonexistent element' means here ;)

Comment: @i-- Does that make more sense now?  I edited the question

Comment: @Downvoter  Could I have the vote back please?  I think I explained myself very clearly.  If not let me know what I should clarify.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you haven't styled the div with any width, height, margin, or padding you can leave it as is.  No need to add "display: inline;".  It's natural display: block; is just fine and won't take up any space as long as it is empty.

Then, if you inject content with, say, javascript the div will grow to fit the inside content.

Comment: It adds a newline sometimes!

Comment: It does if there is styling assigned to the div, often in base styles.  To ensure this isn't the case with your container make sure to give it a class such as .user-container, and style that with padding: 0; margin: 0; height: auto; etc.  If you still find issues, you may want to look at the line-height style as well.

Comment: I did not assign any style to the div however!  What would you suggest I do to remedy the situation?  Should I make it a different tag altogether?  For example `<divthatdoesntdobadthings />`

Comment: I tried that and I think that is working fine.  So I will go ahead and do that instead of using a `div`

Comment: Hi @Curious.  I'm very interested in understanding the trouble you are having with the div creating space.  It might be an older-browser issue.  Please take a look at this codepen: http://codepen.io/haltersweb/pen/dMrZxY.  Let me know which of your browsers renders a gap.  The browsers I have tried don't render a gap but you may have a different version then I do.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently a `div` has some display properties by default in the browser.  Using a tag like `<placeholder>` seems like a good alternative that does not affect the UI at all.